# Filtering query results with mongoose on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing an app with mongoose to access MongoDB.

And what I'm trying to achieve is to make a query and discar some documents by id.

```
User.find({})
    .where('price').lt(upperLimit)
    ....
    .exec(function(err, users) {
      //
    });
```

The point is I want to discard some users that I know before doing the query. Any ideas?. I don't want to post-process users collections and filter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nin/#_S_nin) operator to exclude an array of `_id` values:

```
User.find({})
  .where('price').lt(upperLimit)
  .nin('_id', idsToExclude)
  ....
  .exec(function(err, users) {
    //
  });
```

Comment: I would suggest not using the $nin operator if possible and rather use the $ne operator as $nin is not capable of using an index (indexes are only inclusive not exclusive) thus forcing a table scan across all documents.

Comment: @christkv Actually, neither `$nin` nor `$ne` use indexes effectively (see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#using-ne-and-nin-in-a-query-is-slow-why)), but as @nutlike noted in his comments, `$ne` doesn't work in this case.  As long as another query term is included first (in this case `price`) the `$nin` only needs to scan through the docs with the matching price, not the whole collection.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [$ne](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ne/) operator:

```
User.find({"_id":{"$ne":<IdToExclude>}}). …
```

Comment: Ok, but if its, an array of objects?

Comment: For arrays you could use the [$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/) operator. `User.find({"ids":{"$ne":{"$all":[<FirstIdToExclude>,<SecondIdToExclude>,…]}}}). …`

Comment: I think JohnnyHK approach is the better one but could you let us know if this one works too?

Comment: I just checked it myself and it does not seem to work, sorry! Stick to JohnnyHK's answer for arrays.